# Site-to-site VPN connection build by AWS

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services

I met a question regarding how to build a site to site VPN from on-premise network to an AWS Virtual Private Cloud, which of the following might be combined and configured?  [Select 4]

Can anyone help to explain why option C and F are wrong.

- **A**. An on-premise customer Gateway.
- **B**. A Virtual Private Gateway
- **C**. A Virtual Customer Gateway
- **D**. A VPC with Hardware VPN Access
- **E**. A private subnet in your VPC
- **F**. A NAT instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those answers are correct. First, the NAT instance is used to enable instances in a private subnet accessed from the internet. Secondly, there is no such thing as A Virtual Customer Gateway, it's just a Customer Gateway.